# PubSub from GKE: PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: node.js, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to connect to PubSub from within one of my GKE cluster by using the [nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub) client but get permission issues, no matter the IAM service account or list of OAuth scopes used in the cluster configuration.

While testing locally, everything works fine. I've tried various things, such as using the same account that I was using to successfully connect to PubSub while testing locally in my remote GKE, using a service account with the project owner permission, or setting the scopes manually, but nothing seems to do the trick, and I always face the same permission denied error:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action. 
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26) 
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52) 
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:342:141) 
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:305:181) 
at /node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:124:78 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

I am quite lost given that I can connect to my other services (Redis, SQL, BigTable, ...) without any issue from this GKE instance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed this instruction https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages ?

Comment: Those are instructions to use in AppEngine, but I am having issues connecting from GKE, and I don't think there should be any extra configuration steps required except providing the correct permissions to the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was actually on my end. I was overriding the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable in my YAML file, causing libraries that directly used this variable to use the wrong service account file. The cluster would still show the correct file, but another one would be used in the background.